# can't access "Joomla Access Controls" after upgrade from 4.2.19 to 4.7.25

Tags: joomla, permissions, 500

I've just gone through a long incremental upgrade process from CiviCRM 4.2.19 to 4.7.25. Thought everything was working well until I discovered non-admin users were getting permission denied errors, so I tried to check the ACL settings -- and I can't access the Joomla Access Control settings.

When I go to "Administer->Users and Permissions->Permissions (Access Control)" and click "Joomla Access Control", the popup window shows

"500 - An error has occurred. JHtml: :bootstrap not supported. File not found."

Error logs aren't helpful -- nothing in PHP or CiviCRM logs, and Apache error just reports that the request for "/administrator/index.php?option=com_config&view=component&component=com_civicrm&tmpl=component" has returned a 500.

Help appreciated!

System details:

- Joomla 2.5.28 (yes I know it needs upgrading, that's happening as
  part of this whole site upgrade!)
- CiviCRM 4.7.25
- PHP 5.6

Answer (score 1):

OK so in reviewing the requirements in the documentation, it seems that version 4.6.x was the last version that states explicitly it is compatible with Joomla 2.5 AND 3. The latest documentation (which I'm assuming is for 4.7?) says Joomla 3 is required.

But the download site clearly says "Download 4.7.27 for Joomla 2.5x/3x".

I'll try a rollback to 4.6.32 and see if the problem persists.

UPDATE: 4.6.32 solves this issue.  So I guess 4.6.32 is the last version of CiviCRM that works with Joomla 2.5, so I have to stay with it until the Joomla site can be upgraded to 3x.

Would be very helpful if the download page were updated to reflect this.